# Using data from payload globally in python

Tags: python, flask

I need to use user's setup configuration in a Flask APP. The user will post certain data ( id, age etc) and I have to use this configuration in other methods as well. Now this is what I have tried which is not working

```
data_config = {}

@app.route('/api/data', methods=['POST'])
def check():
    payload = request.get_json()
    data_config = payload
    print(data_config)
    return jsonify(data_config)
```

I am getting the data in `data_config` . But  when I make the following call I am getting data empty

```
@app.route('/api/get_config', methods=['GET'])
def getCofig():
    return jsonify(data_config)
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `global` missing. Try this:

```
data_config = {}

@app.route('/api/data', methods=['POST'])
def check():
    global data_config
    payload = request.get_json()
    data_config = payload
    print(data_config)
    return jsonify(data_config)
```

---

BTW your solution looks hacky, maybe you could consider saving `data_config` into a database?

Comment: This is the answer, but OP, really really don't use `global`. There is 99.9999% of the time a better solution and you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: using DB was in consideration. This will solve the problem I was dealing with. Thanks for the help